# How to decide in which direction the bone deforms the mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, weight-painting

I have this rigged mesh. The thigh is deformed as I expected:

[image]

Just for experiment, I paint some weight of thigh bone on waist:

[image]

But why does it deform like this? The thigh bone moves forwards, while the painted waist moves backwards.

[image]

I know I shouldn't paint weight like this. This is purely for studying how bone animation works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that the bone extends in both directions, but that the pivot point stays the same.  Since the area that you weight painted is on the other side of the pivot point it will rotate in the opposite direction that you move the bone, because that's the direction the imaginary extension rotates in.